# Orchard CMS widget Display Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I have a widget which is using a query to display details. Is it possible to specify the display type of the widget (the query is using Summary and all is displayed as i want) because the header of the widget has a display type of Detail and i want it to use summary so i can override the shape when i place it in different sections (mainly the header text), but when in the content zone i would want it to be details. I am using the bootstrap theme. So basically if i stick my widget any where other than content i want it to use summary

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're looking for widget alternates, not changing the display type.

Comment: I was hoping to do it by alternate displaytype  but the widget renders as display type detail everytime so i haven't really got much to go by. If oncreating a widget u specify its view or similar u could. I maybe wrong but can't  figure an alterative .

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, i have tried lots of shapes overwrites but they only have: display(model.content) no access to the title or anyother parts. Am i missing a trick here, as i cant find how to change a simple thing like how to change display the title of the widget ie make it h3 instead of h2 etc..

Comment: Not "alternate displaytype", alternates. You do not need a different display type. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates For widgets in particular, make sure you enable the widget alternates feature. The shape tracing feature can help you figure out what alternate to use (but don't enable that in prod).

Answer (score 3):

Ah, we meet again.

Widgets are built and injected into the layout in a class called `Orchard.Widgets.Filters.WidgetFilter`. There doesn't appear to be any way to modify the display type used for a widget (the default `WidgetFilter` uses the default value of "Detail").

To get around this, you can use your own implementation of `WidgetFilter`. Copy the existing code into your own class, and add an `[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Widgets.Filters.WidgetFilter")]` attribute to your class. This will make sure that the existing `WidgetFilter` isn't used, and yours is.

If you read through the `OnResultExecuting` method, you'll see that right near the end there is a call to `BuildDisplay`. The second argument to this method can be a display type. You can check `widgetPart.Record.Zone` to see where the widget has been placed, and pass in different values for the displayType parameter accordingly.

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way, but it's where I'd start. Perhaps someone else might have a neater solution.

Comment: I am not following this solution (probably my fault). First off, I hope that you do not have to do something as heavy handed as replace a part of the widget framework. That aside, it looks like your solution is persisting the `DisplayType` and I think that @Jon wants to get this value dynamically based on runtime information. Did I misread this?

Comment: @Philip You are right, I must have got a bit carried away with my example - have edited to more directly answer Jon's question. I wouldn't say replacing a part of the widget framework is "heavy handed", it's all designed to be overridden in this fashion.

Comment: @Philip You've made me paranoid that I've missed something painfully obvious now ;) As far as I can see, once you get into IContentManager's `BuildDisplay`, the display type becomes immutable because it is passed around in a BuildDisplayContext. So you can access the display type in implementors of IContentHandler and IContentTemplateFilter, but not alter it. I'm still learning Orchard so by all means prove me wrong!

Comment: mdm thanks again for helping, you seem to be a guru of orchard. I will dive deeper into the code from your answer to see what i can do. @Philip I though it may be possible when creating a widget to somehow tell it to use a certain display type ie: summary or detail. Then i can create a shape overide for the respective one. But from the above it seems not or complicated if possible. Maybe there is a better solution, any other ideas. Thanks

Comment: It has been a while since I dug deep into Orchard, so I do not propose an answer. My hope, though, is that you may access this information in the Driver or solve it by creating a more custom cshtml. I am pretty sure the latter is possible. Play around with the [Designer Tools](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools) from your development environment and you should be able to override almost everything you need in a cshtml (razor) template. Look for videos on it. With that, you may find your answer. And do not forget to post the solution here.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens i will take a look at the designer tools as well. I will keep the post up to date with any solution or further questions be more likely. Thanks

Comment: I have done it using a mulitple shapes overrides ie asidefirst/second and again for  other places i put the widget. Seems overkill as if i had access to display type i could use just summary layout override  . Maybe i am doing or looking at this wrong but i have it working for this. i have other problems but will post in new questions as they arise. Thanks all